# Self-referential values in an R config file

Tags: r, config

Using the [config](https://github.com/rstudio/config) package, I'd like elements to reference other elements, 
like how `path_file_a` references `path_directory`.

config.yml file in the working directory:

```
default:
  path_directory  : "data-public"
  path_file_a     : "{path_directory}/a.csv"
  path_file_b     : "{path_directory}/b.csv"
  path_file_c     : "{path_directory}/c.csv"
  # recursive     : !expr file.path(config::get("path_directory"), "c.csv")
```

Code:

```r
config <- config::get()

config$path_file_a
# Returns:  "{path_directory}/a.csv"

glue::glue(config$path_file_a, .envir = config)
# Returns: "data-public/a.csv"
```

I can use something like [`glue::glue()`](https://glue.tidyverse.org/) on the value returned by `config$path_file_a`.
But I'd prefer to have the value already substituted so `config$path_file_a` contains the actual value (not the template for the value).

As you might expect, uncommenting the `recursive` line creates an endless self-referential loop.

Are there better alternatives to `glue::glue(config$path_file_a, .envir = config)`?

Comment: It looks like this is not yet possible: https://github.com/rstudio/config/issues/21

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I came across the same problem and I've written a wrapper around config and glue.
The package is called [gonfig](https://github.com/SuperMayo/gonfig) and has been submitted to CRAN.

With it you would have:

***config.yml***

```
default:
  path_directory  : "data-public"
  path_file_a     : "{path_directory}/a.csv"
  path_file_b     : "{path_directory}/b.csv"
  path_file_c     : "{path_directory}/c.csv"
```

And in your R script:

```
config <- gonfig::get()
config$path_file_c
#> "data-public/c.csv"
```